# Tensorflow ) How to input many image files to train?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I got an error ***when loading many image files for training from disk***  below:

> IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

I searched for a solution and what I found is below:

```
ulimit -n NUMBER
```

In my situation, however , I can not command that because of

> the issue of permission

I do not have sudo permission so that I can not use that.

What I want to do is **`to add summary of test for visualizing test accuracy`**.

My code is below:

```
test_data = get_data(is_test=True)
test_x, test_labels = features_from_data(test_data, is_test=True)
test_merged = tf.summary.merge([accuracy1_summary, accuracy2_summary, accuracy3_summary])
test_summary = sess.run(test_merged, feed_dict={x_: test_x, y_: test_labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
test_writer.add_summary(test_summary, i)
```

But with these codes(especially with the first line), I'm getting the error above

> : The part loading image files from disk.

***So I have to solve this by the technique of programming.***
Is there any solution for it?
Thank you.

*** UPDATE : The method 'loadImages()','get_data()' is below:***

```
def loadImages(fnames,is_test):
    path = os.getcwd() + "/dataset/train_images/"
    if is_test:
        path = os.getcwd() + "/dataset/test_images/"
    loadedImages = []
    for image in fnames:
        img = Image.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages

def get_data(is_test=False):
    data_path = "train"
    if is_test:
        data_path = "test"
    return pd.read_csv('dataset/'+data_path+'.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1",
                names=['FILENAME', 'TITLE', 'CATEGORY_ID'])
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question, but no luck so far. What causes the "too many open files" error? And how is that related to visualizing accuracy?

Comment: @jsalonen That's my responsibility, sorry. I updated my question(especially, the code part) when loading images from disk, this error occured. Visualizing accuracy is the final goal , the error occured in the process of acieving that goal.

Comment: Okay so the issue on this question is `IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`? How many files you then have and where do you load them? If that happens in `get_data` can you open up that method as well. If there are other separate issues, I would add them as new, separate questions.

Comment: @jsalonen I think you understand right, There are 6,000 files and the default limit of system is 1024 on my computer. I uploaded the mehotd 'get_data()'.

Comment: How do you get so many files opened? Are you running `get_data` inside a loop?

Comment: @jsalonen I think the method 'loadImages()' keeps making the error and the method is executed in the method 'features_from_data'. sorry for misleading. I'm in debugging.

Comment: You open the images, but where do you close them?

Comment: @jsalonen That was my mistake and I solved it by copying the one and closing the original one. Thanks.